# Why does foldr applied to a function strict in both arguments not cause a stack overflow?

Tags: haskell, recursion, stack-overflow, fold

I wonder why this expression doesn't cause a stack overflow in GHCi:

```
foldr (+) 0 [1..5000000] -- 12500002500000
```

Obviously, `(+)` is strict in both its arguments so the whole list has to be traversed immediately and lazyness doesn't help.

My first thought was that the compiler would recognize `(+)` as an associative operation and transforms it into tail recursion.

However, the following operation does work as well:

```
foldr (-) 0 [1..5000000] -- -2500000
```

What is happening here?

Comment: Actually, it does kind of cause a stack overflow – just not on the fixed-size stack but on the demand-growable heap. So it doesn't crash your program but instead your OS... not at only 5000000 elements, but if you try much more, be prepared for some swapping fun.

Comment: I should hope it doesn't crash a modern OS.

Comment: @chepner not crash, but it can bring it down to almost standstill when the kernel starts swapping out the window manager to make room for the rogue Haskell programm. Compiling with `-with-rtsopts '-M4g'` or similar is advisable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GHC's latest runtime system lets its stack grow dynamically. Try limiting it, and you'll see your stack overflow:

```
% ghci +RTS -K512K
GHCi, version 8.2.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> foldr (+) 0 [1..5000000]
*** Exception: stack overflow
```

Comment: Why was the stack size limited in the first place? This makes rather sense for imperative languages, where loops are idiomatic and recursion is not.

Comment: @ftor I don't know for sure, but I suspect it is a 32-bit computing legacy. When you only have 4 gigs to play with, memory management can actually be an issue that requires attention; and a popular strategy is to pick a fixed-size stack, put it at a particular place in the address space, and use the rest of your address space for heap. Once you move to 64-bit addresses that becomes much less of an issue, as it's easy to put your stack and heap in wildly different parts of the address space -- there is technically still a limit, but not one RAM will be able to match for a long time.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is how memory management still works, but I remember dealing with stack-heap collisions on classic Mac OS in the 90s. The stack started at address space 0 and grew up; the heap started at <some-high-address> and grew down. Allocate too much memory on either, and one would start to overwrite the other. (Of course, each process was allocated a fixed-sized chunk of the global address space, rather than a full 32-bit virtual address space, so it was a lot easier to consume available memory.)